# Google Endpoints in iOS with Google Sign-in

Tags: ios, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to setup the `Client API` files for Google Endpoints in iOS, I generated all the files fine but now when I try to import them (foo.h and foo_Sources.m) into my project I keep getting build errors saying

> GTLDefines.h file not found

```
#if GTL_BUILT_AS_FRAMEWORK
  #import "GTL/GTLDefines.h"
#else
  #import "GTLDefines.h" //error on this line of the files
#endif
```

Since I have already integrated Google Sign-in (with GoogleOpenSource.framework) I am not suppose to manually bring in files from the `GTLSource project`. I did it just to see what would happen and I get lots of errors saying `multiple interfaces/properties defined` in all the files.

So how am I suppose to fix the error of GTLDefines.h missing?

these are the [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_ios) I am going off of to do this. The docs still references the now deprecated Google+ login api, are the instructions still the same from the new google sign-in api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding out that the new Google Sign-in API does not require the `GoogleOpenSource.framework`. I removed it then added the files from the `GTLSource project` and everything compiled fine